# Unrecognized Android S please retry with version 2021.2.1 or newer

Tags: android

Unrecognized Android Studio (or Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA) version '202.7660.26.42.7486908', please retry with version 2021.2.1 or newer.

when i study android studio,i meet with this problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTuMx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please Update your Android Studio to latest version it will solve your error